# Showing a integral equation has a solution

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Show that the equation $$\cos(\pi t/2) + \int_{0}^1 \frac{e^{-50s}}{1+t} f(s)^3 ds - f(t)=1$$ has a solution in $C([0,1]).$

Let $Tf(t)=\cos(\pi t/2) + \int_{0}^1 \frac{e^{-50s}}{1+t} f(s)^3 ds-1$. I'm now trying to show that $$\|Tf(t) - Tg(t)\| \le C\|f-g\|_\infty$$ in order to use Banach's fixed point theorem.

What I have is that $$\|Tf(t) - Tg(t)\| = \left \|  \int_{0}^1 \frac{e^{-50s}}{1+t} \left(f(s)^3  - g(s)^3\right)  ds\right \| \le \int_{0}^1 \left \|  \frac{e^{-50s}}{1+t} \right \|   \left \| \left(f(s)^3  - g(s)^3\right) \right \| ds$$ and since $ \left \| \left(f(s)^3  - g(s)^3\right) \right \| \le \|f^3-g^3\|_\infty$ I get $$\|Tf(t) - Tg(t)\| \le \frac{\|f^3-g^3\|_\infty}{1+t}\int_{0}^1 e^{-50s} ds = \frac{e^{50}-1}{50e^{50}+50e^{50}t} \|f^3-g^3\|_\infty.$$

But how can I get rid of these third powers in the second factor here?

Comment: As currently written the integral is independent of $t$. Is this a typesetting error ?

Comment: @Leucippus It is not, the integral depends only on $s$.

Comment: In this case the integral is just a constant and leaves $f(t) = \frac{c_{0}}{1+t} - 2 \, \sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi x}{4}\right)$ as the solution.

Comment: What happens to the term $f(s)^3$? @Leucippus

Answer (score 1):

As given $$\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right) + \int_{0}^1 \frac{e^{-a s}}{1+t} \,  f^{3}(s) \,  ds - f(t) = 1.$$
By making some adjustments this can be seen as
$$ \int_{0}^{1} e^{-a s} \, f^{3}(s) \, ds = (1+t) \, \left( f(t) + 2 \, \sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi t}{4}\right) \right).$$
Differentiating both sides with respect to $t$ leads to
$$ 0 = \frac{d}{dt} \, \left[ (1+t) \, \left( f(t) + 2 \, \sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi t}{4}\right) \right) \right]. $$
This leads to
$$ f(t) = \frac{c_{0}}{1+t} - 2 \, \sin^{2}\left(\frac{\pi t}{4}\right). $$

Note: the integral
$$ \int_{0}^{1} e^{-a s} \, f^{3}(s) \, ds $$
has no variable association with $t$ and is a constant. With use of $f(t)$ one can compute the integral and obtain an equation involving $c_{0}$ which can be solved. Otherwise the solution contains $\sin^{2}(x)$ and can be used that a solution exists in the desired range.